# Need help taking information from classes/sub-class in javascript and producing HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I am learning Javascript through a Udemy course by Jonas Schmedtmann and I wanted to take a coding challenge I did in his course and turn the console.log into HTML text. The issue I am having is that I always get undefined or other errors when trying to take information from ES6 classes and push into HTML. I have spent a few hours lurking the internet for a solution but I'm honestly not sure what to try as I am new to Javascript myself

I tried returning values as constructors, I tried array.sort, I've tried forEach but I am 100% sure I lack understanding of some the basic elements of JS.

```
class Element {
    constructor(name, buildYear){
        this.name = name;
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
    }
}

class Park extends Element {
    constructor(name, buildYear, area, numTrees) {
        super(name, buildYear);
        this.area = area; //km2
        this.numTrees = numTrees
    }
    treeDensity() {
        const density = this.numTrees / this.area;
        console.log(`${this.name} has a tree desnity of ${density} trees per square km.`)
    }
}


const allParks = [new Park('Pawnee Commons', 2012, 0.2, 215), 
new Park('Bloomingdale Park', 1894, 2.9, 3500), 
new Park('Marine Park', 1975, 0.4, 980)];



function calc(arr) {
    const sum = arr.reduce((prev, cur, index) => prev + cur, 0);
    //destructing example
    return [sum, sum / arr.length];
}



function reportParks(p) {
    console.log('-------PARKS REPORT-------');

    //Density
    p.forEach(el => el.treeDensity());

    //average age
    const ages = p.map(el => new Date().getFullYear() - el.buildYear);

    const [totalAge, aveAge] = calc(ages);
    console.log(`Our ${p.length} parks have an average of ${aveAge} years.`)

    //which park has the most trees
    const i = p.map(el => el.numTrees).findIndex(el => el >= 1000);
    console.log(`${p[i].name} has more than 1000 trees`);
} 


reportParks(allParks);

///////This is where I try to figure out how to push ANY data from allParks

function parksHtml() {
    document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML = ?????????;
}
parksHtml();
```

A basic example would be I am able to do allParks[1].name for textContent or innerHTML but I am unable to provide the whole array as textContent. I would like to ideally provide everything I console.log to be pushed into the textContent but am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 3):

`textContent` and `innerHTML` need to be strings.  Instead of setting `el.innerHTML` to equal an array, or object, or whatever, convert it to a string. `JSON.stringify()` is the easiest general way to do this. If you want *all* of the text that is `console.log`'d in the course of a function to be stored into the HTML element, one way to do this is to create an empty string variable near the top of the function

```
var outputStr = '';
```

And then wherever you call `console.log` instead append the text to the output with a newline.

```
outputStr += `Our ${p.length} parks have an average of ${aveAge} years.\n`;
```

And then finally return the string at the end of the function. Then you can set the `textContent` to equal the result of the function.

```
el.textContent = someFunctionReturningAString();
```

If you want it to modify a specific HTML element directly, instead of creating an output variable, you can just modify the `textContent` as the function goes:

```
// At the top of the function
el.textContent = ''

// ... function contents

el.textContent += `Our ${p.length} parks have an average of ${aveAge} years.`

// etc
```

Perhaps passing in the specific element you want to modify as an argument to the function, or storing it in the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Element {
    constructor(name, buildYear){
        this.name = name;
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
    }
}

class Park extends Element {
    constructor(name, buildYear, area, numTrees) {
        super(name, buildYear);
        this.area = area; //km2
        this.numTrees = numTrees
    }
    treeDensity() {
        const density = this.numTrees / this.area;
        console.log(`${this.name} has a tree desnity of ${density} trees per square km.`)
    }
}


const allParks = [new Park('Pawnee Commons', 2012, 0.2, 215), 
new Park('Bloomingdale Park', 1894, 2.9, 3500), 
new Park('Marine Park', 1975, 0.4, 980)];



function calc(arr) {
    const sum = arr.reduce((prev, cur, index) => prev + cur, 0);
    //destructing example
    return [sum, sum / arr.length];
}



function reportParks(p) {
    console.log('-------PARKS REPORT-------');

    //Density
    p.forEach(el => el.treeDensity());

    //average age
    const ages = p.map(el => new Date().getFullYear() - el.buildYear);

    const [totalAge, aveAge] = calc(ages);
    console.log(`Our ${p.length} parks have an average of ${aveAge} years.`)

    //which park has the most trees
    const i = p.map(el => el.numTrees).findIndex(el => el >= 1000);
    console.log(`${p[i].name} has more than 1000 trees`);
} 


reportParks(allParks);

///////This is where I try to figure out how to push ANY data from allParks

function parksHtml() {
    document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML = allParks.map(elem => `<p>${elem.name}</p>`).join('');
}
parksHtml();
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you both. I learned something today and tried it both of your ways. Much appreciated

Comment: @mike3640 Awesome! Accept one of the answers if it solved your original question.